# SPSS: generate 'fake' survey data using rv.uniform without losing value labels

Tags: label, spss

I have a pretty straightforward survey dataset. Each row is a respondent, and each column is a question. Responses have a value that is a whole number, and each number has a label.

Now, I need to replace all of those values with fake data to use in a training. I need something that looks and feels like the original dataset, but isn't actually client data.

I started by replacing my variables with random number values:

```
COMPUTE Q1=RV.UNIFORM(1,2). 
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE Q2=RV.UNIFORM(1,36). 
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE Q3=RV.NORMAL(50, 13).
EXECUTE.
```

(rv.normal/rv.uniform depending on what kind of data I'm trying to fake - age versus multiple-choice question, for example).

This works, but then when I try and generate crosstabs, export the dataset w value labels, etc., the labels aren't applied to the columns with fake data. As far as I can tell, my fake numbers are in the exact same format they were in before - numeric, no decimals, width of 2, nominal. The labels still appear in the variable view, but they aren't actually being applied.

I'd really prefer not to have to manually re-label every one of these columns, because there's quite a few of them. Any ideas for how to get around this issue? Or is there a smarter way to generate fake data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `RV.UNIFORM` and the `RV.NORMAL` functions do not generate integers - they generate decimal numbers. You may have your display hide the decimal numbers by having 0 decimals in the variable view, but they are still there (you can check this by adding decimals in the variable view).
So you neen another step of turning your decimals into integers. For example, the following are two ways to get a random 1 or 2 (integers):

```
COMPUTE Q1=rnd(RV.UNIFORM(1,2)).
```

or

```
COMPUTE Q1=trunc(RV.UNIFORM(1,3)).
```

Once the numbers generated are integers corresponding to the value labels definition, you should be able to see the labels in the output.